# what is the maximum size of excell that can be exported from vs 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, export-to-excel

In my website when I tried to export the data to excel file I am getting the "System out of memory" exception. What is the maximum size of the excel which can be exported. My record contains around 300,000 columns. Is it because of the size of the record or is there any other reason?? Please help

Comment: You can also refer to this for more details : http://superuser.com/a/366473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you get depends by your computer performances (available memory) and how your code handles memory.

On the other hand an xlsx file can have a maximum of 16384 columns and an xls file can have 256 columns.